# Spring Batch Admin:Job status is not getting updated from Started to Completed

Tags: java

i am working on application based on Spring Batch and Spring Batch Admin. When job starts, it's status is changing from Starting to Started.
When job is completed. Status stills appears as Started.However, it should change as Completed.

This status comes from Spring Batch database tables present in the database. Status changes as Completed in tables however in UI it does not update.

Please do help me with this issue.